# How can I disable network activity on Aptana (Eclipse IDE) until I save it to speed it up?

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana

I'm working on a mapped network drive with Aptana. Some activity is making it very slow. Keystrokes may takes seconds to appear. I don't know what activity is causing the problem (background synchronization, backup tmp files, whatever ...), but I need to speed it up.

Any ideas?

Note: This question may apply to any Eclipse variant, but since I'm only using Aptana, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the files directly form the mapped network drive, you cannot disable nothing. Depending on how the network connection is made through VPN or a Samba share or whatever, you can see delays. It happen to me while working on VPN. Make a local copy, synchronize it with your network resource only from time to time and this should prevent lags. This is also safer as working directly over various protocols can result in abnormal file erasure. It happen to me while editing directly over FTP.

Now I work in Aptana on a local copy in my local webserver, and from time to time I synchronize with the live version on the live server.